# Is $\mathbb{Q^{*}}$ under multiplication isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ under multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I need to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Q^{*}}$ under multiplication is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ under multiplication. However, I am not entirely sure if my proof is correct.

Note that $\mathbb{Q^{*}}$ is the set of all nonzero rationals, and $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ is the set of all positive rationals greater than $0$.

***Proof:***

To verify if these two groups are isomorphic, I first define the map $h(x)=x^2$, where $x\in \mathbb{Q^{*}}$ and $x^2 \in \mathbb{Q^{+}}$. Then, I need to check whether the mapping $h$ is injective, surjective, and operation preserving.

**Injectivity**: Suppose $h(x)=h(y)$. Then, $x^2 = y^2$, and, after taking the square root of both sides of the equation, we get that the result is $x=y$ as desired.
**Surjectivity**: Let $y\in\mathbb{Q^{*}}$. However, we get that $y=x^2$, from where we conclude that $x=\sqrt{y}$ or $x=-\sqrt{y}$, which implies that $x$ might as well be an irrational number.

Since this mapping is not surjective, we conclude that there is no isomorphism from $\mathbb{Q^{*}}$ under multiplication to $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ under multiplication.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Your map isn't injective since $h(-1)=h(1)$. But,  so what? That just shows that this particular map isn't an isomorphism. That doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: Notice that $\Bbb Q^+$ has a very simple structure: it's the free $\Bbb Z$-module with a countable basis.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed: it's not a duplicate, author shows work, and mistakes of kind "some mapping is not an isomorphism, thus there is no isomorphism" are quite common.

Comment: @mihaild The question is asked very often, and the "mistakes" are also always similar, in fact quite common as you said. I went for his first sentence "I need to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Q^{*}}$ under multiplication is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ under multiplication. " So there is a need, which the duplicate fully satisfies. But I can also understand different viewpoints.

Answer (score 2):

You correctly conclude that your map isn't an isomorphism, but it doesn't imply there is no isomorphism - may be some other map is? For example, there is surjection that preserves operation: $f(x) = |x|$.

To show that there is no isomorphism, we need to find some property that is preserved under isomorpshim, that is true in one set and false in other.

One such property is having non-trivial root of unity. Let $f$ be operation preserving map $\mathbb Q^* \to \mathbb Q^+$. Note that it's necessary that $f(1) = f(1 \cdot 1) = f(1) \cdot f(1)$, thus $f(1) = 1$ (there are no other solutions to $x = x \cdot x$ in $\mathbb Q^+$). But we also have $f(-1) \cdot f(-1) = f(1) = 1$, and the only solution to $x^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb Q^+$ is $x = 1$ (unlike $\mathbb Q^*$, where there is also solution $x = -1$). Thus we have $f(-1) = 1$, and so $f$ isn't injective, and thus not isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $x^2=y^2$ implies $x= y$ or $x=-y$. Since your domain contains negative rational too, so your map is not one to one.

But there is something interesting in your map! If you reverse the domain and co domain with the same $h$, you get *$\mathbb{Q^+}$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself* !